# How to bind two target properties to a single source property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a very complicated UI problem involving 2 groups of `RadioButtons`.
At any given time, only 1 group can be **enabled**.  However, each group can have a different **checked** (selected) button.

These `RadioButtons` all affect the same source property, which stores an integer value ranging from 1 to 5.  However, I only want to propagate the new value to the source property when a `RadioButton` is both **enabled** and **checked**.

Since the UI allows for **disabled** `RadioButtons` to be **checked**, the source property should be updated when a **checked** `RadioButton` is **re-enabled** as well.

Here is an image demonstrating the UI layout:
[image: RadioButton layout]
*(Group 1 is Enabled, Box 1 is Checked; Group 2 is Disabled)*

Now, this originally seemed like the job for an `IMultiValueConverter`, but there are some intricacies that make this rather complex:

- The propagation only happens in one direction, **OneWayToSource**.
- `IMultiValueConverter` does not allow for multiple target properties to convert into one source property.

Due to the above seemingly contradicting constraints, it doesn't make sense to use an `IMultiValueConveter`.  This is because the `ConvertBack` method only allows for 1 target property; the source property values are the result.

For my scenario, `RadioButton.IsEnabled` and `RadioButton.IsChecked` are the two target properties that must convert into the integer value, which I had hoped to pass as the `ConverterParameter`.

The data model for the image above has two notable properties (and shouldn't have any more):

- GroupNumber
- Severity *(this is the integer corresponding to the nested `RadioButton`)*

So, what can I do in a situation like this?  My objective is to only modify the view component of the application.

**Edit: XAML for the `RadioButtons`:**

```
<RadioButton Name="Group1" GroupName="OuterGroup" IsChecked="True">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Group 1"/>
        <StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=IsChecked}" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton Content="1" GroupName="Group1" />
            <RadioButton Content="2" GroupName="Group1" />
            <RadioButton Content="3" GroupName="Group1" />
            <RadioButton Content="4" GroupName="Group1" />
            <RadioButton Content="5" GroupName="Group1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</RadioButton>

<!--Group2 is the same...-->
```

---

## [Optional] Application of the problem:

In my program, there are 3 outer `RadioButtons`.  Each `RadioButton` corresponds to the a type of mood: **happy, sad, or indifferent**.  The numbers 1 to 5 are used to identify how happy or sad the mood is;  it doesn't make sense to describe the intensity of indifference (being partially sad, but more happy, indicates the mood type should be happy, not indifferent).

That being said, there are two properties in the real data model:

- MoodType
- Severity

Perhaps this provides more insight into why I want to bind multiple targets to a single source. ;)

Comment: Is it acceptable for you to check outer group (Happy, Sad, Indifferent) when any item from respecatable group is checked? I.e. if I click on 3 in Happy then Happy become checked. This way you can bind items in all groups to Severity property and MoodType will be updated automatically

Comment: Yes, the nested `RadioButtons` are enabled when the outer `RadioButton` is checked.  The inner `RadioButtons` make up the **Content** of the outer `RadioButtons`.  I'll post the relevant XAML for this behavior.

Comment: I meant that if you make them all enabled and if user check Severity in any group you select that group. This way outer radiobutton works more like indicator of what mood is chosen. Also this is one less click for user to tell what is his mood and severity

Comment: That would require a `Severity` property for each group.  I'm trying to do this with only one property (perhaps I need to change it).  This is because user can switch the selected group without changing the `Severity` of a particular group.  Also, I think the UI benefits from the grayed-out appearance of the deselected mood type.  Yes, it is an extra click, but it shows the user more vividly what mood type is selected.

Comment: You can highlight currently selected group and remove outer radiobutto completely. So if user thinks he is Happy for 3 he just clicks 3 across Happy (and Happy becomes selected). And you bind all inner buttons to single Severity property but also bind MoodType to the currenlty active group. Worth a try?

Comment: Sounds like it would work.  It would require 1-click selection, otherwise the `Severity` property may be incorrect, so no disabling.  I'll take a look at changing the UI.  However, the original question still remains (if it even has an answer haha)

Comment: Could it be that you only have 5 severity radiobuttons, and 3 mood buttons, and lay them out more intuitively? I mean, all the info is in these two sets of controls. Choose mood, then severity, and severity applies to whatever mood you selected.